# How to define a destructor of a class B if B uses class A (c++)?

Tags: c++

I have a class `A`.
`A` has its own destructor.

I use `A` to define `B` as follows.

```
class A{
  protected:
    int* array;
  public:
    A(int size){array = new int[size];}
    ~A() { delete [] array;}

}

class B{
 public:
  A x;
}
```

How should I define the destructor for `B`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to define a destructor for B.  B's member variables will always be destroyed when B is destroyed.

Comment: Only make your destructor virtual if you intend the object to be polymorphic.  Don't just blindly do it.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to do anything special with class `B`. The compiler generated destructor will do the right thing in this case.

class `A` on the other hand is either missing an assignment operator and a copy constructor, or you have to disable these by making them private. The compiler generated ones will cause problems if you copy or assign an `A` instance (and hence, a `B` instance too. See [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: +1 for the rule of three. Also, the code above won't compile as given if you try to instantiate a `B` object.

Comment: juanchopanza Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to define a destructor for `B`. `B` doesn't have any members which need manual clean up. When an instance of `B` is destroyed the destructors of all of it's members are called (whether or not you have a user defined destructor), which means the instance of `A` is cleaned up by it's own destructor. Therefore the default destructor is perfectly fine for `B`.

Of course you are missing a custom copy constructor and assignment operator for `B` to satisfy the rule of three, but thats a different matter.

Comment: You mean for A, right? Thanks, I did't know the rule of 3. I was just going to ask the question why do I need to define the constructor and assignment operator as juanchopanza suggested.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler generated destructor is called (for which you don't need to do a thing), the destructor for A will automatically be called.

Basically, you don't need to do anything to destruct B properly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing `B` needs to do in its destructor. You do need to either define a default constructor for `A` or call its existing constructor in `B`s default constructor